# locating a file I recently opened

Tags: macos

I opened an Illustrator file the other day that I found quite back accident while searching for another file. Now that I am purposefully trying to find it, Of course I cannot. Unfortunately I don't remember what it I named it. But considering I just opened it it should not be all that hard to find again? But it is proving to be more difficult than I thought. Any suggestions please. I already asked this question in graphic design and I was told that I should ask it here. Thank you.

This is a reply I got, "Your operating system has likely a way to search files using the last access time as a criterion. This in combination with a file extension should return a manageable list of files to check. But how to do this on your specific OS is a question for SuperUser, not GraphicDesign."

Comment: Do you have that file on your hard disk? Then you could just search for all illustrator files and sort by date. If it was on some website you could check your browser history.

Comment: It is on my desktop. I found it while searching for another file from years ago.

Comment: Maybe this video will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjtQvAmE6OU

Comment: Thank you SpiderPig, I will watch the video. I am sorry SpiderPig. I should have mentioned I have a Mac, I am not used to asking computer questions online.